# Invalid elif syntax in python

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to learn how to use python and i've always wanted to make my own discrod bot so I tried using discord.py but I added elif to make it so it's more optomized and so if no command goes through but the correct prefix is used then a help message goes through but I somehow have my elif syntax wrong heres my code the error is on line 33, and I use replit if that makes a diffence

```
import discord
import os
import random
from random import randint

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith('%%'):

    if message.content.startswith('%%help'):
      embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Commands", description="Fine here's a list of commands", color=0x00ff00)
      embedVar.add_field(name="%%coin", value="randomly says heads or tails", inline=True)
      embedVar.add_field(name="%%messagedev", value="sends me a message that I unfortanatly cannot repond to", inline=True)
      embedVar.add_field(name="%%die @exaple", value="puts a funny message with whoever you @ dying", inline=True)
      embedVar.add_field(name="%%wrk", value="randomly gives you money that you immediatly burn because it wont be saved cause I haven't yet made a system to record you balence", inline=True)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

    elif message.content.startswith('%%coin'):
      await message.channel.send(random.choice(['Heads','tails']))

    elif message.content.startswith('%%messagedev'):
      dmes = message.content.replace("%%messagedev","")
      print(('{}:{}').format([(message.author.name),(dmes)])

    elif message.content.startswith('%%die'):
      dinput = message.content.replace("%%die","")
      await message.channel.send(random.choice(['looks like{} got deadified'.format(dinput), 'looks like{} got 360 no scoped'.format(dinput), 'looks like{} got totally rekt and died'.format(dinput)]))

    elif message.content.startswith('%%wrk'):
      rrnngg = (randint(1,500))
      rand = random.choice(["DANG! he be working you earn {}$ that you immediatly burn because it wont be saved cause I haven't yet made a system to record you balence".format(rrnngg), "DANG! he be not working you earn 0$""])
      await message.channel.send('{}'.format(rand))
      
    else: await message.channel.send('Hey not sure if mispled or whatever but for help use %%help')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the line before that.

Comment: Use an IDE that automatically checks for balanced brackets.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't noticed that I spent so much time thinking I somehow had my indentation out of whack somehow thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar notified me I'm missing a ) on the line before that just posting it as an answer so I can mark this as resolved.